# How to store sprites in an array in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I want to store the obstacles in my game in an array so that I can generate a random number and draw a random sprite from the array. So here are my questions:

1. How to store sprites in an array?
2. How to access the sprites in array and use them?

Comment: Why this post is getting down voted ? Please tell so that I can improve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can either create sprites and then store it in array

```
let arr = [];
let sprite1 = this.add.image(400, 300, 'spritekey1');
arr.push(sprite1);
let sprite2 = this.add.image(400, 300, 'spritekey2');
arr.push(sprite2);
let sprite3 = this.add.image(400, 300, 'spritekey3');
arr.push(sprite3);

// To get Random element from array use Phaser's Utility function
let randomSprite = Phaser.Utils.Array.GetRandom(arr);
```

2) Or you can create group like this

```
let group = this.add.group();
let sprite1 = this.add.image(400, 300, 'spritekey1');
let sprite2 = this.add.image(400, 300, 'spritekey2');
let sprite3 = this.add.image(400, 300, 'spritekey3');    
group.add(sprite1);
group.add(sprite2);
group.add(sprite3);

// group.getChildren() returns an array
let randomSprite = Phaser.Utils.Array.GetRandom(group.getChildren());
```

Group examples [here](https://labs.phaser.io/index.html?dir=game%20objects/group/&q=) would be useful.
Group [Documentation.](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Group.html#getChildren__anchor)

Using *Phaser* provided utility function to get random element is *easiest* and *straight forward* approach.
`Phaser.Util.Array.GetRandom()` [documentation.](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Utils.Array.html#.GetRandom__anchor)